# Get Total and Total where is null in same query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table  called Lapt**strong text**opStock with **LaptopStockID** as primary key (each laptop we have in stock gets a unique key)  ,**userid** of who is using that specific laptop (the laptop's don't have to have a userid), and a **LaptopID** which refers to another table **Laptop** which contains all the info about that specific model of laptop (each model has a **LaptopID**)

What I am trying to achieve is a table with the full model name in the first column (EX: Dell XPS 15 2020)
they will be "group by" the model, then in the second column I want the total amount of each model where userid is null (to see how many are free for use) and in the 3rd column I need the total amount of those laptops in stock

so far I have this:

`SELECT CONCAT(a.Model,' ',a.BouwJaar) as Model, count(*) as total  FROM Laptopstock as b inner join laptops as a on a.LaptopID = b.LaptopID GROUP BY CONCAT(a.Model,' ',a.BouwJaar)`

[image]

That is the result, so the total amount of laptops.

so all I would need now is how to I get the amount where is null into the same table?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select concat(l.Model, ' ', l.BouwJaar) as Model, count(*) as total,
       sum(ls.userId is null)
from Laptopstock ls inner join
     laptops l
     on l.LaptopID = ls.LaptopID 
group by l.Model, l.BouwJaar;
```

Note that I changed the table aliases to abbreviations for the table names.  Learn to use *meaningful* table aliases rather than arbitrary, meaningless letters.